# How to save/capture photo in portrait mode in IOS AVFoundation? Xcode 10.2 Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, orientation

I set photoOutput.connection orientation to portrait but image continues to save in landscape mode. Am I supposed to change the settings somewhere else?

```
func configurePhotoOutput() throws {

        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }


        self.photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

        self.photoOutput?.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        self.photoOutput?.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true 

        self.photoOutput!.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG])], completionHandler: nil)


        if captureSession.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput!) { captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutput!) }

        captureSession.startRunning()

    }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

When photo is being captured, inside delegate method of AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate where you get the image at that time you have to provide orientation for the image.

```
var cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .front

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if let image = photo.cgImageRepresentation()?.takeUnretainedValue() {
        let finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: 1, orientation: UIDevice.current.orientation.getUIImageOrientationFromDevice(for: cameraPosition))
        print(finalImage)
    }
}

extension UIDeviceOrientation {
    func getUIImageOrientationFromDevice(for position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> UIImage.Orientation {
        if position == .front {
            switch self {
            case .portrait, .faceUp: return UIImage.Orientation.leftMirrored
            case .portraitUpsideDown, .faceDown: return UIImage.Orientation.left
            case .landscapeLeft, .unknown: return UIImage.Orientation.down // this is the base orientation
            case .landscapeRight: return UIImage.Orientation.up
           }
        } else {
            switch self {
            case .faceUp, .landscapeLeft, .unknown: return UIImage.Orientation.up
            case .portraitUpsideDown: return UIImage.Orientation.left
            case .portrait, .faceDown: return UIImage.Orientation.right
            case .landscapeRight: return UIImage.Orientation.down
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working for me. Please let me know if you're having any issue in the above code.

Comment: When saving to UIImage you will loose information such as depth map of the photo.